# What does "lower density" mean in this problem?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

> If $\mathscr{U}$ is a ultrafilter on $\omega$, then $\mathscr{U}$ contains a subset $A$ of lower density zero.

This is an exercise on page 76 of *Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory*, Peter Komjath , Vilmos Totik. I don't know the meaning of  "lower density" .

One definition of "lower density" I found is a function: $\phi: 2^{\mathbb{R}} \to 2^{\mathbb{R}}$, such that, for any $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then any $x \in \phi(E)$:$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{m(E \cap[x -h, x+h])}{2h}=1$$

Does "lower density" in the problem have some connection with this definition?

Comment: Entirely a guess, but a set $S\subset\mathbb N$ then we can define the density of $S$ as $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|S\cap \{1,2,\dots,n\}|}{n}$$ That isn't always defined, but the $\liminf$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Upper_and_lower_asymptotic_density) gives the following definition: the lower density of a set $A \subset \omega$ is
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{|A \cap \{1, \dots, n\}|}{n}.$$
In other words, find the fraction of the first $n$ integers that are in $A$, and take the liminf as $n \to \infty$.  The upper density is similar but with a limsup.

Comment: Not quite right: you need to replace $\{1,\dots,n\}$ by $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Actually, those definitions are equal - ignoring zero doesn't affect the answer. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: I personally dislike thinking of $0$ as an ordinal number, personally.  I think of ordinals as a result in a race. There is no $0$th person across a finish line in a race.

Comment: @Thomas: Of course, but it’s still a slightly counterintuitive way to express a simple idea.

Comment: @Thomas: Then you simply have a picture of the ordinals that doesn’t agree with that in common use. You’d do better to think of the ordinal as an indication of who beat you in the race.

Comment: Which is why I said "personally." :) @BrianM.Scott I realize that it is an uncommon view.  There isn't any functional difference whether you choose $0$ or $1$ as the first ordinal, but I find the fact that $3$ is the the fourth ordinal somewhat irritating.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I considered starting at 0 as you say but couldn't decide which was clearer.  Density is more often used for subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ rather than $\omega$ in which case my definition looks better.  Of course as mentioned, they are equivalent.

Comment: @Thomas: Clearly mileage varies considerably! I find it very pleasant that $3$ is preceded by $3$ ordinals. $0$-based indexing is **very** convenient much of the time.

Comment: @Nate: For me $\Bbb N=\omega$, and what you call $\Bbb N$ is either $\Bbb Z^+$ or $\omega\setminus 1$. And I think that you can safely assume that anyone who is using $\omega$ is starting at $0$.

Comment: I find the notation $\omega\setminus 1$ for $\omega\setminus\{0\}$ to be infuriating. That's not edifying, and it relies on a particular representation of ordinals in set theory rather than in any "true" sense of ordinal. That representation is powerful, I agree, but it is a model inside set theory for a concept.

Answer (score 3):

It has at most a distant connection. If $A\subseteq\omega$, the *lower (asymptotic) density* of $A$ is

$$\underline{d}(A)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\{a\in A:a<n\}|}n\;;$$

see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Upper_and_lower_asymptotic_density).

Answer (score 3):

At the back of the book you are reading, there is a glossary of concepts. The definition of lower density is on p. 500.