# Ultrafilters on $\omega$ and lower/upper density

Tags: set-theory, filters

> (Show that)If $\mathscr{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $\omega$, then $\mathscr{U}$ contains a subset $A$ of [lower density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325571/what-does-lower-density-mean-in-this-problem) zero. (But) there is an ultrafilter on $\omega$ such that every $A \in \mathscr{U}$ has positive upper density.

This is an exercise on [page 76](http://books.google.com/books?id=HGF3jkEaI-wC&pg=PA76) of *Problems and Theorems in Classical Set Theory*, Peter Komjath , Vilmos Totik. I have no clue how to start.

Comment: While I admit I don't know this subject, I don't see a question here. Do you have to prove that there's an ultrafilter on $ \omega $ such that every $ A \in \mathscr{U} $ has a positive upper density?

Comment: The lack of question marks. These are all statements.

Comment: @Waleed: There are obviously two questions: to show that every ultrafilter on $\omega$ contains a set of lower density $0$, and to show that there is an ultrafilter on $\omega$ whose every member has positive upper density.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I didn't think it was so obvious 28 minutes ago.

Comment: @Waleed: So I gathered. I just find that rather surprising.

Comment: By _upper density_ do you mean the definition given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density#Upper_and_lower_asymptotic_density)?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Yes, though I'm not absolutely sure. Because it's not defined in the book.

Comment: You are aware that the book also contains [solutions](http://books.google.com/books?id=HGF3jkEaI-wC&pg=PA342), right? (BTW I think this is a very good book; judging from the parts I went through.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Oh, my goodness! BTW, Thanks for adding the link.

Comment: @user14111: My bad. I should admit, at the moment, I feel quite embarrassed. It must be meaningless for me to provide reasons why I failed to notice that.Perhaps the only thing I can do is to promise that won't happen again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first question (Nr. $6$ in the book), follows immediately from Nr. $5$:

> If $\mathscr{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $\omega$ and $0=n_0<n_1<\dots$ are arbitrary natural numbers, then there exists an $A\in\mathscr{U}$ with $A\cap[n_i,n_{i+1})=\varnothing$ for infinitely many $i<\omega$.

For $k>0$ take $n_k=k!$, say. To prove the result in Nr. $5$, let $\langle n_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ be such that $0=n_0<n_1<\dots~$. Let $$A=\bigcup_{k<\omega}[n_{2k},n_{2k+1})\;;$$ clearly $$\omega\setminus A=\bigcup_{k<\omega}[n_{2k+1},n_{2k+2})\;.$$ Both $A$ and $\omega\setminus A$ have empty intersection with infinitely many of the intervals $[n_k,n_{k+1})$, and since $\mathscr{U}$ is an ultrafilter, one of $A$ and $\omega\setminus A$ is in $\mathscr{U}$.

For the second question, let $\mathscr{I}=\{A\subseteq\omega:\overline{d}(A)=0\}$, where $\overline d$ is the upper density. It’s not hard to verify that $\mathscr{I}$ is an ideal, so $\mathscr{F}=\{\omega\setminus A:A\in\mathscr{I}\}$ is a filter on $\omega$. Now just let $\mathscr{U}$ be any ultrafilter containing $\mathscr{F}$.